# Orbeon Internal XForms submission unauthorized

Tags: orbeon

After migration from Obreon Forms 3.8 to 4.9, this submission:

```
<xf:submission id="make-wsdl-as-zip" method="post" xxforms:show-progress="false"
            action="/services/wsdl-in-zip" replace="all" instance="wsdl">
</xf:submission>
```

gives an error:

> 2015-06-18 11:07:43,951 INFO  ProcessorService  - /resource/wsdl.xform
>   - Received request 2015-06-18 11:07:43,954 INFO  PageFlowControllerProcessor  - unauthorized {controller:
>   "oxf:/page-flow.xml", method: "POST", path: "/resource/wsdl.xform",
>   status-code: "403"} 2015-06-18 11:07:43,955 INFO  ProcessorService  -
>   HttpStatusCodeException(code = 403, resource = None, throwable = ) at
>   line 41, column 47 of oxf:/config/prologue-servlet.xpl (executing
>   processor: element='[...]',
>   name='{http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors}page-flow') 2015-06-18
>   11:07:43,955 INFO  ProcessorService  - /resource/wsdl.xform - Timing:
>   4

I am not using `RequestDispatcher`. Orbeon is deployed on Tomcat and is only changed in its web.xml, which is the sandbox-directory location.

What is wrong?

Comment: How is `/resource/wsdl.xform` mapped in your `page-flow.xml`? It might be that a POST to a `<page>` is now prevented by default. See [Authorization of Pages and Services](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Controller-~-Authorization-of-Pages-and-Services).

Comment: It is a post to <page>,  I assume I have to set "page-public-methods" property to provide Backward compatibility?

Comment: Is it in effect as service or a page? If a service, I would use `<service>` instead, as that indicates the intent better.